# General purpose IQueryable<T> over remote IEnumerable<T>

Tags: linq, wcf, iqueryable

I have an in-memory dataset of strongly typed objects (~100000) which are accessible through IEnumerable-collections.

Now I would like to query this dataset from another computer.

I can set up a self-hosted WCF-service to open up access to this dataset, but how do I do if I want clients to be able to query this dataset using LINQ?

I know about IQueryable-provider and that they seem very hard to implement.

My question is, are there any general purpose implementation of an IQueryable-provider for my case where a client is supposed to be able to query an in-memory IEnumerable over WCF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx) might be an option but I have not used them for a long time and can not tell how much effort it takes to make them work with an in-memory collection. I can only tell that using them with Entity Framework is quite straight forward but it looks like the [reflection data provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd672591.aspx) should work for you.